# PHP Error : Undefined Index ($_POST Variable)

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to do a PHP connection script, with form and data processing in the same page, but when I try my code I always get 2 errors :

> Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Site FTM\connexion.php on line >7
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\Users\Simon\Documents\Site FTM\connexion.php on line 18

I understand that PHP don't find the index called 'password' in $_POST, but I'm sure that the form is leading to the same page (#)... Can somebosy help me ? Here is the whole code, on PasteBin : http://pastebin.com/A9z1HHvf

Sorry, the error messages are in french, but all the other variable names are in english. You just need to know that $errDisplay is use to store all my custom error messages and display them at the bottom ofmy page.

Comment: And what does your code look like? Especially line 18...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is problematic:

```
$isFormOK = isset($_POST['username']) AND isset($_POST['password']);
```

`AND` has [lower precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `=`, that's why this line reads like this:

```
( $isFormOK = isset($_POST['username']) )
  AND isset($_POST['password']);
```

In other words, whether or not `$_POST['password']` is in the script, it works the same way - setting `$isFormOk` value based only on `$_POST['username']` existence.

What you should do instead is either use `&&` form of boolean `and` (it has higher precedence than `=`):

```
$isFormOK = isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']);
```

... or, even better, just use the fact that `isset` can take more than one argument:

```
$isFormOK = isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
```

Quoting [the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only
>   if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right
>   and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['password'])){
$pass = $_REQUEST['password'];
}
```

Now You can use `$pass` as it contains the values which is being posted.

Comment: The OP's code already references `$_POST['password']` - all `$_REQUEST` does is take both `GET` and `POST`